# How to render Vulkan's scene to ImGui window

Tags: vulkan, imgui

https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/issues/5110

Version: 1.87
Branch: docking

**Back-end/Renderer/Compiler/OS**

Back-ends: imgui_impl_Vulkan.cpp + imgui_impl_Vulkan.cpp
Operating System: MacOS

**My Issue/Question:**

How to render Vulakn's scene to ImGui window?

want to achieve this：

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQLrk.png)

I have read various documents and [#914](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/pull/914),but I'm still at a loss.
Maybe I'm close to the answer?
Here is [my project code](https://github.com/1111mp/Vulkan), built quickly via CMake. It is implemented with reference to the [Vulkan tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Texture_mapping/Images).
Also would appreciate any help, thanks a lot.

The key code is [here](https://github.com/1111mp/Vulkan/blob/5ad98054511fc13be061e42daf19acd6cb0ea110/src/Application.cpp#L346):

```
m_Dset = ImGui_ImplVulkan_AddTexture(m_TextureSampler, m_TextureImageView, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL);
...
ImGui::Begin("Viewport");

ImVec2 viewportPanelSize = ImGui::GetContentRegionAvail();
ImGui::Image(m_Dset, ImVec2{viewportPanelSize.x, viewportPanelSize.y});

ImGui::End();
```

I tried several ways:

1. According to this code I got it：

```
m_Dset = ImGui_ImplVulkan_AddTexture(m_TextureSampler, m_TextureImageView, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL);
...
ImGui::Begin("Viewport");

ImVec2 viewportPanelSize = ImGui::GetContentRegionAvail();
ImGui::Image(m_Dset, ImVec2{viewportPanelSize.x, viewportPanelSize.y});

ImGui::End();
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmzBR.png)

2. According to this code I got it：

```
m_Dset = ImGui_ImplVulkan_AddTexture(m_TextureSampler, m_SwapChainImageViews[currentFrame], VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL); 
// std::vector<VkImageView> m_SwapChainImageViews;
...
ImGui::Begin("Viewport");

ImVec2 viewportPanelSize = ImGui::GetContentRegionAvail();
ImGui::Image(m_Dset, ImVec2{viewportPanelSize.x, viewportPanelSize.y});

ImGui::End();
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtqNi.png)

But when I drag the ImGui window to the main window:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfeaO.png)

3.last attempt:

```
// remove m_Dset =  ImGui_ImplVulkan_AddTexture(...);
...
ImGui::Begin("Viewport");

ImVec2 viewportPanelSize = ImGui::GetContentRegionAvail();
ImGui::Image(m_DescriptorSets[currentFrame], ImVec2{viewportPanelSize.x, viewportPanelSize.y});

ImGui::End();
```

I got it:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deP6p.png)

Hope you understand what I mean......Any help would be greatly appreciated.It can be quickly reproduced with the items provided above, if you have the time.
I've been stuck for days.

ps: I'm working tirelessly on problems I've encountered while learning Vulkan and ImGui. I have a cold because of it. 
I must be low IQ.

I have these variables:

```
private:
    GLFWwindow *m_Window;
    VkInstance m_Instance;
    VkDebugUtilsMessengerEXT m_DebugMessenger;
    VkPhysicalDevice m_PhysicalDevice = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
    VkDevice m_Device;
    VkQueue m_GraphicsQueue;
    VkQueue m_PresentQueue;
    VkSurfaceKHR m_Surface;
    VkSwapchainKHR m_SwapChain;
    std::vector<VkImage> m_SwapChainImages;
    VkFormat m_SwapChainImageFormat;
    VkExtent2D m_SwapChainExtent;

    std::vector<VkImageView> m_SwapChainImageViews;
    VkRenderPass m_RenderPass;
    VkDescriptorSetLayout m_DescriptorSetLayout;
    VkPipelineLayout m_PipelineLayout;
    VkPipeline m_GraphicsPipeline;
    std::vector<VkFramebuffer> m_SwapChainFramebuffers;
    VkCommandPool m_CommandPool;

    // for imgui
    VkDescriptorPool m_ImGuiDescriptorPool;
    VkRenderPass m_ImGuiRenderPass;
    std::vector<VkFramebuffer> m_ImGuiFramebuffers;
    VkCommandPool m_ImGuiCommandPool;
    std::vector<VkCommandBuffer> m_ImGuiCommandBuffers;

    VkImage m_TextureImage;
    VkDeviceMemory m_TextureImageMemory;
    VkImageView m_TextureImageView;
    VkSampler m_TextureSampler;

    VkImage m_DepthImage;
    VkDeviceMemory m_DepthImageMemory;
    VkImageView m_DepthImageView;

    VkBuffer m_VertexBuffer;
    VkDeviceMemory m_VertexBufferMemory;
    VkBuffer m_IndexBuffer;
    VkDeviceMemory m_IndexBufferMemory;
    // UniformBuffer
    std::vector<VkBuffer> m_UniformBuffers;
    std::vector<VkDeviceMemory> m_UniformBuffersMemory;
    VkDescriptorPool m_DescriptorPool;
    std::vector<VkDescriptorSet> m_DescriptorSets;

    std::vector<VkCommandBuffer> m_CommandBuffers;
    std::vector<VkSemaphore> m_ImageAvailableSemaphores;
    std::vector<VkSemaphore> m_RenderFinishedSemaphores;
    std::vector<VkFence> m_InFlightFences;

    QueueFamilyIndices m_QueueFamilyIndices;

    uint32_t currentFrame = 0;
    uint32_t m_ImageCount = 2;

    VkDescriptorSet m_Dset;
```

```
void initVulkan()
    {
        createInstance();
        setupDebugMessenger();
        createSurface();
        pickPhysicalDevice();
        createLogicalDevice();
        createSwapChain();
        createImageViews();
        createRenderPass();
        createDescriptorSetLayout();
        createGraphicsPipeline();
        createCommandPool(&m_CommandPool);
        createDepthResources();
        createFramebuffers();
        createTextureImage();
        createTextureImageView();
        createTextureSampler();
        createVertexBuffer();
        createIndexBuffer();
        createUniformBuffers();
        createDescriptorPool();
        createDescriptorSets();
        createCommandBuffers();
        createSyncObjects();

        IMGUI_CHECKVERSION();
        ImGui::CreateContext();

        ImGuiIO &io = ImGui::GetIO();
        (void)io;
        io.ConfigFlags |= ImGuiConfigFlags_NavEnableKeyboard;
        io.ConfigFlags |= ImGuiConfigFlags_DockingEnable;
        io.ConfigFlags |= ImGuiConfigFlags_ViewportsEnable;

        ImGui::StyleColorsDark();

        // When viewports are enabled we tweak WindowRounding/WindowBg so platform windows can look identical to regular ones.
        ImGuiStyle &style = ImGui::GetStyle();
        if (io.ConfigFlags & ImGuiConfigFlags_ViewportsEnable)
        {
            style.WindowRounding = 0.0f;
            style.Colors[ImGuiCol_WindowBg].w = 1.0f;
        }

        {
            VkDescriptorPoolSize pool_sizes[] =
                    {
                            {VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_SAMPLER, 1000},
                            {VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER, 1000},
                            {VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_SAMPLED_IMAGE, 1000},
                            {VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_STORAGE_IMAGE, 1000},
                            {VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_TEXEL_BUFFER, 1000},
                            {VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_STORAGE_TEXEL_BUFFER, 1000},
                            {VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 1000},
                            {VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_STORAGE_BUFFER, 1000},
                            {VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_DYNAMIC, 1000},
                            {VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_STORAGE_BUFFER_DYNAMIC, 1000},
                            {VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_INPUT_ATTACHMENT, 1000}};

            VkDescriptorPoolCreateInfo pool_info = {};
            pool_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_POOL_CREATE_INFO;
            pool_info.flags = VK_DESCRIPTOR_POOL_CREATE_FREE_DESCRIPTOR_SET_BIT;
            pool_info.maxSets = 1000 * IM_ARRAYSIZE(pool_sizes);
            pool_info.poolSizeCount = (uint32_t)IM_ARRAYSIZE(pool_sizes);
            pool_info.pPoolSizes = pool_sizes;

            if (vkCreateDescriptorPool(m_Device, &pool_info, nullptr, &m_ImGuiDescriptorPool) != VK_SUCCESS)
                throw std::runtime_error("Create DescriptorPool for m_ImGuiDescriptorPool failed!");
        }

        // Create RenderPass for m_ImGuiRenderPass
        {
            createImGuiRenderPass();
        }

        // Create CommandPool for m_ImGuiCommandPool
        {
            createCommandPool(&m_ImGuiCommandPool);
        }

        // Create CommandBuffers for m_ImGuiCommandBuffers
        {
            createImGuiCommandBuffers();
        }

        {
            createImGuiFramebuffers();
        }

        ImGui_ImplGlfw_InitForVulkan(m_Window, true);
        ImGui_ImplVulkan_InitInfo init_info = {};
        init_info.Instance = m_Instance;
        init_info.PhysicalDevice = m_PhysicalDevice;
        init_info.Device = m_Device;
        init_info.QueueFamily = m_QueueFamilyIndices.graphicsFamily.value();
        init_info.Queue = m_GraphicsQueue;
        init_info.PipelineCache = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
        init_info.DescriptorPool = m_ImGuiDescriptorPool;
        init_info.Subpass = 0;
        init_info.MinImageCount = m_ImageCount;
        init_info.ImageCount = m_ImageCount;
        init_info.MSAASamples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
        init_info.Allocator = nullptr;
        init_info.CheckVkResultFn = nullptr;
        ImGui_ImplVulkan_Init(&init_info, m_ImGuiRenderPass);

        // Upload Fonts
        {
            VkCommandBuffer commandBuffer = beginSingleTimeCommands(m_ImGuiCommandPool);
            ImGui_ImplVulkan_CreateFontsTexture(commandBuffer);
            endSingleTimeCommands(commandBuffer, m_ImGuiCommandPool);
            ImGui_ImplVulkan_DestroyFontUploadObjects();
        }

        // m_Dset = ImGui_ImplVulkan_AddTexture(m_TextureSampler, m_TextureImageView, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL);
    }
```

```
void drawFrame()
    {
        vkWaitForFences(m_Device, 1, &m_InFlightFences[currentFrame], VK_TRUE, UINT64_MAX);

        uint32_t imageIndex;
        VkResult result = vkAcquireNextImageKHR(m_Device, m_SwapChain, UINT64_MAX, m_ImageAvailableSemaphores[currentFrame], VK_NULL_HANDLE, &imageIndex);

        if (result == VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DATE_KHR)
        {
            recreateSwapChain();
            return;
        }
        else if (result != VK_SUCCESS && result != VK_SUBOPTIMAL_KHR)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to acquire swap chain image!");
        }

        // Only reset the fence if we are submitting work
        vkResetFences(m_Device, 1, &m_InFlightFences[currentFrame]);

        // vkResetCommandBuffer(m_CommandBuffers[currentFrame], 0);
        recordCommandBuffer(m_CommandBuffers[currentFrame], imageIndex, m_DescriptorSets[currentFrame]);

        {
            // vkResetCommandPool(m_Device, m_ImGuiCommandPool, 0);
            VkCommandBufferBeginInfo info = {};
            info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO;
            info.flags |= VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_ONE_TIME_SUBMIT_BIT;
            vkBeginCommandBuffer(m_ImGuiCommandBuffers[currentFrame], &info);

            VkRenderPassBeginInfo renderPassInfo = {};
            renderPassInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_BEGIN_INFO;
            renderPassInfo.renderPass = m_ImGuiRenderPass;
            renderPassInfo.framebuffer = m_ImGuiFramebuffers[imageIndex];
            renderPassInfo.renderArea.offset = {0, 0};
            renderPassInfo.renderArea.extent = m_SwapChainExtent;
            VkClearValue clearColor = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
            renderPassInfo.clearValueCount = 1;
            renderPassInfo.pClearValues = &clearColor;
            vkCmdBeginRenderPass(m_ImGuiCommandBuffers[currentFrame], &renderPassInfo, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);

            // Record dear imgui primitives into command buffer
            ImGui_ImplVulkan_RenderDrawData(ImGui::GetDrawData(), m_ImGuiCommandBuffers[currentFrame]);

            vkCmdEndRenderPass(m_ImGuiCommandBuffers[currentFrame]);
            vkEndCommandBuffer(m_ImGuiCommandBuffers[currentFrame]);
        }

        updateUniformBuffer(currentFrame);

        VkSubmitInfo submitInfo{};
        submitInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;

        std::array<VkCommandBuffer, 2> submitCommandBuffers =
                {m_CommandBuffers[currentFrame], m_ImGuiCommandBuffers[currentFrame]};
        VkSemaphore waitSemaphores[] = {m_ImageAvailableSemaphores[currentFrame]};
        VkPipelineStageFlags waitStages[] = {VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT};
        submitInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
        submitInfo.pWaitSemaphores = waitSemaphores;
        submitInfo.pWaitDstStageMask = waitStages;
        submitInfo.commandBufferCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(submitCommandBuffers.size());
        submitInfo.pCommandBuffers = submitCommandBuffers.data();

        VkSemaphore signalSemaphores[] = {m_RenderFinishedSemaphores[currentFrame]};
        submitInfo.signalSemaphoreCount = 1;
        submitInfo.pSignalSemaphores = signalSemaphores;

        if (vkQueueSubmit(m_GraphicsQueue, 1, &submitInfo, m_InFlightFences[currentFrame]) != VK_SUCCESS)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to submit draw command buffer!");
        }

        VkPresentInfoKHR presentInfo{};
        presentInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PRESENT_INFO_KHR;

        presentInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
        presentInfo.pWaitSemaphores = signalSemaphores;

        VkSwapchainKHR swapChains[] = {m_SwapChain};
        presentInfo.swapchainCount = 1;
        presentInfo.pSwapchains = swapChains;
        presentInfo.pImageIndices = &imageIndex;
        presentInfo.pResults = nullptr; // Optional

        result = vkQueuePresentKHR(m_PresentQueue, &presentInfo);

        if (result == VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DATE_KHR || result == VK_SUBOPTIMAL_KHR || m_FramebufferResized)
        {
            m_FramebufferResized = false;
            recreateSwapChain();
        }
        else if (result != VK_SUCCESS)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to present swap chain image!");
        }

        currentFrame = (currentFrame + 1) % MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT;
    }

void recordCommandBuffer(const VkCommandBuffer &commandBuffer, const uint32_t &imageIndex, const VkDescriptorSet &descriptorSet)
    {
        VkCommandBufferBeginInfo beginInfo{};
        beginInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO;
        // beginInfo.flags = 0;                                 // Optional
        // beginInfo.pInheritanceInfo = nullptr; // Optional

        if (vkBeginCommandBuffer(commandBuffer, &beginInfo) != VK_SUCCESS)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to begin recording command buffer!");
        }

        VkRenderPassBeginInfo renderPassInfo{};
        renderPassInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_BEGIN_INFO;
        renderPassInfo.renderPass = m_RenderPass;
        renderPassInfo.framebuffer = m_SwapChainFramebuffers[imageIndex];
        renderPassInfo.renderArea.offset = {0, 0};
        renderPassInfo.renderArea.extent = m_SwapChainExtent;

        std::array<VkClearValue, 2> clearValues{};
        clearValues[0].color = {{0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}};
        clearValues[1].depthStencil = {1.0f, 0};

        renderPassInfo.clearValueCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(clearValues.size());
        renderPassInfo.pClearValues = clearValues.data();

        vkCmdBeginRenderPass(commandBuffer, &renderPassInfo, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);

        vkCmdBindPipeline(commandBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, m_GraphicsPipeline);

        VkBuffer vertexBuffers[] = {m_VertexBuffer};
        VkDeviceSize offsets[] = {0};
        vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(commandBuffer, 0, 1, vertexBuffers, offsets);

        vkCmdBindIndexBuffer(commandBuffer, m_IndexBuffer, 0, VK_INDEX_TYPE_UINT16);
        vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(commandBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, m_PipelineLayout, 0, 1, &descriptorSet, 0, nullptr);

        vkCmdDrawIndexed(commandBuffer, static_cast<uint32_t>(indices.size()), 1, 0, 0, 0);

        vkCmdEndRenderPass(commandBuffer);

        if (vkEndCommandBuffer(commandBuffer) != VK_SUCCESS)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to record command buffer!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pls upload images directly to StackOverflow so they are not lost over time.

Comment: Nr. 2 seems to mostly work. It looks like some infinity mirror going on when the ImGui is embedded. I think you just need to get to the swapchain image before the ImGui modifies it. Perhaps for simplicity sake just copy the rendering out beforehand to a different VkImage.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have re-edited.
`get to the swapchain image before the ImGui modifies it` how should i do this?

Comment: Depends how ImGui is integrated. In general I would assume just making a `vkCmdCopyImage` before any of the ImGui commands in the command buffer.

Answer (score 0):

For me image just not rendering in ImGui::Image and i don't know why. I saw my image in shader inputs, but in shader outputs i had just black color.
I guess in your case you should render your scene to another image (not swapchain image). And it means that you need to use another render pass for it. Use swapchain images only for imgui output.

Answer (score 0):

I think when we `createSwapChain();` set

```
VkSurfaceFormatKHR surfaceFormat;
surfaceFormat.format = VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
surfaceFormat.colorSpace = VK_COLORSPACE_SRGB_NONLINEAR_KHR;
```

like this to avoid validation error!